# Where do I find the shout Fire Breath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My friend had a shout called *Fire Breath*. It did a lot of fire damage.

I was wondering where do I find it?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the shout called Fire Breath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fire Breath can be found at:

- Dustman's Cairn (quest locked)
- Sunderstone Gorge
- Throat of the World

Here's a list of all Dragon shouts and their locations:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Shouts

Comment: There is an "Frost Breath" and an "Fire Breath". 
Locations are in the Link Above.

But, in my opinion,the damage of "Fire Breath" isn't that great, even with 3 Words